# Amazon SNS delivery receipts: do they indicate delivery to mobile or delivery just to the push notification service?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I want to know whether AWS SNS (Simple Notification Service) delivery receipts indicate:

1. whether AWS SNS delivered the push notification just to the relevant push notification service (e. g. GCM, APNS), or
2. whether the push notification was actually delivered to the mobile phone of the targeted user

The documentation appears vague on this.

I'd also like to know if, in case the second case above is true, whether the delivery receipts are also delivered when the app has been force-killed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

SNS supports GCM over HTTP only, so you will only know when SNS has delivered the message to GCM not to the device. In order to get a delivery receipt that the message has been received by the device you would have to use XMPP.

See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#upstream-response) for more.